# JAVA LDAP : How do I obtain the Dn?

Tags: java, ldap

I did an LDAP Directory Search and received some results. I need to iterate over these results and display the Dn for each entry.

In my test environment I returned the Dn value by obtaining the value of the entryDN attribute.

In the production environment the entryDN attribute always returns null.

In both environments when I return the value of the Dn attribute all I get is null.

What I really need to do is reliably obtain the Dn from any environment.

Suggestions?

Comment: Which of about five possible APIs are you using?

Comment: show us some code...

Comment: And also explain to us why your development and production LDAP servers are set up differently. As you are now experiencing, this is just a way to miss bugs until production deployment, and thereafter to waste a lot of time. Somebody must fix that.

Answer (score 1):

To reliably get the Dn use the method SearchResult.getNameInNamespace();

Comment: *If* he's using JNDI.

Answer (score 0):

Building on user2135970's answer, it's not pretty to mix JNDI with Spring LDAP, but it can be done:

```
  private String getDistinguishedName(String addtlFilter) throws NamingException {
    String dn = null;
    LdapContextSource contextSource = (LdapContextSource) ldapTemplate.getContextSource();
    SearchControls ctrls = new SearchControls();
    ctrls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    DirContext dc = null;
    try {
      dc = ldapTemplate.getContextSource().getContext(contextSource.getUserDn(), contextSource.getPassword());
      final String filter = String.format("(&(%s)%s)", addtlFilter, searchFilter);
      NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = dc.search(searchBase, filter, ctrls);
      if (results.hasMore()) {
        dn = results.next().getNameInNamespace();
      }
    } finally {
      if (dc != null) {
        dc.close();
      }
    }
    return dn;
  }
```